# nextjs - pass image as props to be used with next/image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have my index.js as following

```js
import Head from 'next/head'
import Layout, { siteTitle } from '../components/layout'
import Homecard from '../components/homecard'
import logo from '../public/images/logo.jpg'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>{siteTitle}</title>
      </Head>
      <div className='d-flex'>
        <Homecard img={logo} />
      </div>

    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Here is my Homecard component

```js
import styles from '../styles/homecard.module.css'
import Image from 'next/image'

export default function Homecard({ img }) {

    return (
        <div style={{width: '33.33%'}}>
            <Image src={img} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

I receive this error

```
Error: Image with src "/images/logo.jpg" must use "width" and "height" properties or "layout='fill'" property.
```

If I add the fill layout image is not responsive, if I don't image is not displaying.
If I change my Homecard component like this it works.

```js
import styles from '../styles/homecard.module.css'
import Image from 'next/image'
import logo from '../public/images/logo.jpg'

export default function Homecard({ img }) {

    return (
        <div style={{width: '33.33%'}}>
            <Image src={logo} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "gray-matter": "^4.0.3",
    "next": "latest",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "remark": "^14.0.2",
    "remark-html": "^15.0.1"
  }
}
```

How pass image as component props without that error ?

**EDIT**

I changed my markup like so

```js
<div style={{position: "relative",width: '100px', height: '100px'}}>
    <Image src={logo} layout='fill' />
</div>
```

Error is gone but it's not responsive, image is distorted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After been searching since a while I found that discussion on nextjs github page it seems that I'm not the only that encounter this issue

```js
{/* https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18739#discussioncomment-344932 */}
<div className={styles.imageContainer}>
    <Image src={logo} layout='fill' className={styles.image}/>                    
</div>
```

```css
.imageContainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.imageContainer>span { /* OR change span to div */
    position: unset !important;
}

.image {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100% !important;
    position: relative !important;
    height: unset !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i just found out how to do this:-
(pls don't mind the long tailwind classes)

get your component:-

```js
const ImageCard = ({imageSrc,name,title,experience}:ImageCardProps) => {
  return (
    <div className='w-52 h-fit group relative overflow-hidden rounded-md  outline outline-2 outline-Theme-cream'>
        <Image 
            src={imageSrc} 
            alt='test'
            width={208}
            height={300}
        />
        <div className='absolute w-full h-full bg-Theme-black/40 flex items-center justify-center -bottom-10 group-hover:bottom-0 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 transition-all duration-300'>
            <div className='text-white text-2xl relative top-20 p-2'>
                <h1>{name}</h1>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p>Exp {experience} yrs</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ImageCard
```

and for the type `ImageCardProps` :-

```js
type ImageCardProps={
    imageSrc: StaticImageData;
    name: string;
    title: string;
    experience: number;
}
```

we can use `StaticImageData` Interface to assign image as props in next Image component.

now just:-

```js
import test from '../../public/test.png';
import ImageCard from './components/card/ImageCard';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
    <ImageCard imageSrc={test} name='timothy lewis' title='Co-lead' experience={10}/>
    </main>
  )
}
```

also the nextjs Image component requires following properties to work:-

```js
<Image 
     src={imageSrc} 
     alt='test'
     width={208}  //this width
     height={300} //this height

     //this are the width & height mentioned in the error in you question
/>
```

works for melet me know if there's a better way